# Nested nodes in sphinx extension

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx, docutils

I am trying to make a sphinx extension (for html output) that generates a code block and inserts text and `span`s into it.

However when I create a `literal_block` (code block) and add `inline`s (spans) to it, only the text of the inline nodes will appear inside the code block but not as span elements.

```py
from docutils import nodes
from docutils.parsers import rst
from sphinx.addnodes import highlightlang

class MyDirective(rst.Directive):
    # for simplicity and debug purposes no content is used for now
    has_content = True
    
    def run(self):
        node = nodes.literal_block()
        node += nodes.inline("",
            text = "Hello World",
            classes = ["myclass"]
        )
        
        return [
            highlightlang(
                lang = "none",
                force = None,
                linenothreshold = -1
            ),
            node
        ]

def setup(app):
    app.add_directive("helloworld", MyDirective)
```

**Expecting** something like

```html
<div class="highlight-none notranslate">
  <div class="highlight">
    <pre><span class="myclass">Hello World</span></pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Getting** something like

```html
<div class="highlight-none notranslate">
  <div class="highlight">
    <pre>Hello World</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```